# Schema diagram for pervasive DB

Tags: sql-server, database-design, pervasive, pervasive-sql, erd

How to get schema diagram for pervasive DB(PCC) there are about 300 tables in my DB so i need a way to generate Schema diagram for that.
If that is not possible is there any way possible to configure pervasive DB to Sql server?
Help is much appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is no schema diagram tool built into Pervasive.  You might be able to use a third party data modeling too that supports ODBC.  As far as linking a Pervasive Database to SQL Server, you can create a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).
You should also ask the vendor of your application for a schema.